# "New" Google Maps has 'stripey' water

Tags: google-maps

Since google launched the 'new' Maps site, I've had display problems with it in Chrome.

It seems only to relate to blue(!), on sea, rivers, lakes.

Firefox and IE doesn't have the issue, even when using the New maps. This is on a 15" Macbook Pro running Win 7 via bootcamp.

Any suggestions for a fix - Or is it a bug...?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried zooming in or out with the browser?

Comment: Yes. that's pretty much what causes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by reinstalling Chrome (even though my previous install was the same version)

Comment: Could be a corruption somewhere, probably impossible to diagnose :) Thanks for posting the answer!